# worklight adapter load another java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

Inside HTTP adapter, I am getting JSON object back from REST service. I need to do some parsing of the reply before returning it back to the client.

I figured I can have another JavaScript file to do the parsing, so not to clatter my `adapter.js` too much.

What I don't know is how to make the 2nd java script file available in my adapter JS.

On client side I would use something like `$.getScript("some.js");` 
JAVA classes can be accessed simply with `classpath.className`, but I can't find any references on how to load another Java Script file!

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have additional JavaScript files referenced from adapter's JS.